# Showing database items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to have a link that only displays the last 10 database submissions with a select number of tables per submission. Hope that makes sense. So in short a can click 'recent submissions' and it will display the last 10 via customer name, submission date, and id number . Currently in the controller i have the following just to test the link but of course it display every table.

```
<h2>LAST 10 SUBMISSIONS</h2>

<%= @posts.each do |post| %>

<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is more of a comment than an answer but I don't have enough rep to leave a comment.

You could retrieve a bunch of @posts, which will be an array of ActiveRecord Relations. That means you can use Ruby's nifty Array methods. Here's an example:

```
@sorted_posts = @posts.sort_by { |p| p.created_at }.take(20)
```

And then pass in @sorted_posts where you currently have @posts in the code you posted above. But for performance and good practice you should probably retrieve that data in the proper format from the query itself.

```
@last_twenty_posts = Post.order("created_at DESC").limit(20) # limit by whatever number you want
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply order the posts by some attribute specifying the submission time (e.g., `created_on`) and limit the results to a number you want. For example:

```
Post.order("created_on DESC").limit(10)
```

This would return the last 10 `Post` objects based on their `created_on` attribute, with the newest first.